# How can I remember editors when Perspective change

Tags: eclipse, rcp, jface

I have two Perspectives and two editor part each.

When preperspective changed to postperspective  , the editor opend is closed . then changed again to preperspective , no editor can be recovered.

How can I rememver the Editor Opend , even when changing perspective occured. and can I recover it again?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior actually contradicts to the Eclipse UI metaphor where editors are shared between perspectives.

So you have to implement your own persistent storage for perpective:editors map. Also look at http://help.eclipse.org/help33/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/debug/ui/sourcelookup/CommonSourceNotFoundEditorInput.html#getPersistable()